# 500 Internal Server Error - wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

today I visite my site web and I get error: 500 Internal Server Error and in my view i get this:

```
�p��1�U��?���D~"1�$�A0.�Х��X����#�B��v��A�z��Sc�ߊ{3$�͗�{{�B�_�Q�"��`��%��ݽ�q{��)�dӚ����lE��] h�^2 �x�cw7�k�μ ?�l���7n8�U��;j��stlx��wR����RX��[J�ݣ׏����jg�H@�M\�Y�ç���ڽr�� ���fР��q��Uf�?�b��B��z秫
```

status code:  500 Internal Server Error

my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 53

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: You should check your server's error log for the details of this error. The 500 response is simply a generic response that is sent to the client: "there is an error and I can't continue".

Answer (score 0):

On my local xampp wordpress configuration your .htaccess file is working.
Have you updated your webserver / PHP version the last days or something?

If not maybe follow the steps mentioned [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons due to which this error occurs, like:

1. Incorrectly configured
2. .htaccess file PHP memory limit
3. Plugins issue

Enable a **debug log** from within WordPress config, it might give a clue to the exact problem.

For this open **wp-config.php** in the root directory and find

> define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Comment it using **//** at the start, then paste the following:

> define('WP_DEBUG', true);
>
> define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
>
> define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
>
> @ini_set('display_errors',0);

This will start outputting errors to a file in wp-content folder called **error.log**

After that you can take the help of this link to fix the internal server error: https://www.navthemes.com/how-to-remove-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/